# Carregamento de vetor de float em registrador xmm

Tags: assembly, nasm

Estou aprendendo sobre instruções SIMD e tentando aplicá-las no meu código. O objetivo é usar `addps` em um exemplo muito simples: que carregue dois vetores `float`, cada um com quatro valores, e some o i-ésimo valor de cada um, armazenando a resposta no vetor `resultado`. Para isso, tentei colocar cada vetor em um registrador `xmm`, e já tentei com `movaps` e `movups`, mas aparentemente sem sucesso.

O código está dessa forma:

```
section .data
    a dd 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f
    b dd 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f
    resultado dd 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
    formato db "Conteúdo = {%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f}", 10, 0
    formatoResultado db "Resultado = {%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f}", 10, 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    movaps xmm0, [a]
    movaps xmm1, [b]

    addps xmm0, xmm1

    movaps [resultado], xmm0

    mov rdi, formatoResultado
    movaps xmm0, [resultado]
    call printf

    mov eax, 60
    syscall

section .externals
    extern printf
```

Estou gerando e executando `arq` assim:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o arq.o arq.asm
gcc -nostartfiles -o arq arq.o -no-pie
./arq
```

E a resposta obtida é

```
Conteúdo = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4}
Conteúdo = {0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7}
Resultado = {172.8, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0}
```

Consegui exibir corretamente os valores dos vetores `a` e `b` carregando-os um a um com `movlpd` para um registrador `xmm` diferente (ver abaixo), o que não é o propósito, já que quero que todos estejam em um mesmo registrador para poder fazer uso de `addps`.

```
movlpd xmm3, [a + 24]
movlpd xmm2, [a + 16]
movlpd xmm1, [a + 8]
movlpd xmm0, [a]
lea rdi, [formato]
mov al, 4
call printf ; Exibe corretamente "Conteúdo do vetor = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4}"
```

Outro ponto que está me intrigando: ao tentar reproduzir o problema usando a diretiva `asm` diretamente em um código C, o resultado correto apareceu:

```
asm( "movaps %1, %%xmm0\n\t"
     "movaps %2, %%xmm1\n\t"
     "addps %%xmm0, %%xmm1\n\t"
     "movaps %%xmm1, %0\n\t"
         : "=m" (c) 
         : "m" (a), "m" (b) 
    );
```

Alguém saberia me dizer onde estou errando e como posso corrigir esse problema?